# Can someone help me identify this larva?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this creature in my toilet bowl and very curious as to what it is. The main reason is I want to make sure this wasn't a parasite living in me.  Everything I've researched tells me this is some sort of fly larva, possibly a fungus gnat larva or a drain fly larva.  The fact that it has no long hairy like things makes me think it is not a pet flea larva.  This was in Southern California and it was almost exactly 1cm long.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Southern California, 1cm long, in the toilet bowl, moves a bit like a caterpillar, symmetrical pairs of what look like prolegs on its body.]

Comment: Singular larva, plural larvae.